# Getting variable out of double function

Tags: javascript

There was already post with same question, but none of answers was doing what i suppose to do. So here is code example:

```
function findIP(onNewIP) {
  var myPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
  var pc = new myPeerConnection({
      iceServers: [{
        urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"
      }]
    }),
    noop = function() {},
    localIPs = {},
    ipRegex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/g,
    key;

  function ipIterate(ip) {
    if (!localIPs[ip]) onNewIP(ip);
    localIPs[ip] = true;
  }

  pc.createDataChannel("");

  pc.createOffer(function(sdp) {
    sdp.sdp.split('\n').forEach(function(line) {
      if (line.indexOf('candidate') < 0) return;
      line.match(ipRegex).forEach(ipIterate);
    });
    pc.setLocalDescription(sdp, noop, noop);
  }, noop);

  pc.onicecandidate = function(ice) {
    if (!ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex)) return;
    ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex).forEach(ipIterate);
  };
}
```

That code is JS function, and after is goes usage:

```
function addIP(ip) {
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = ip;
  document.getElementById("IPLeak").appendChild(li);
}

findIP(addIP);
```

So what this usage is doing, is taking all 3 ip's(local,local ip6 and public ip4) and displaying it with li element.However, what i need, is only one ip address(public ip4), and it need to be stored into variable so i can process it further.  In this case variable which  need to be taken out it's ip variable in function addIP(ip).

I did found one code example which can get variable outside function:

```html
<script>
function profileloader()
{
    profile = []; // no "var" makes this global in scope
    profile[0] = "Joe";
    profile[1] = "Bloggs";
    profile[2] = "images/joeb/pic.jpg";
    profile[3] = "Web Site Manager";
}
profileloader();
document.write("Firstname is: " + profile[0]);
</script>
```

But when i try to implement , problem is how it works with single function while in code there is function executing function, so i was not able to get variable output. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you need to learn about callbacks https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function

you function findIP takes a callback that function gets called a couple of times with an ip, so to log for example all ips you could call

```
findIP(function(ip){console.log(ip)});
```

Comment: I see that command is working, but  i still dont get why not using something like, findIP(function(ip){var x="(ip)"}); it's not working. I read about that callback function but not sure how exactly to make it work.